# Searchview not showing the correct results

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I"m using Recycle view adtper to populate my framgment class iwht json file from online and using searchview, user can search for Title by typing inside searchbox and it will show the filtered results which matches text entered and title from json.

But instead whenever I type any text it show different results. Here is the screenshot 
[image]

[image]

[image]

as you can notice when I type con, It filter different results. Also when I type la it still show results which don't have any word containing "la".

Here is my adapter class

```html
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> implements
        Filterable {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList = new ArrayList<ExampleItem>();
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> contactListFiltered = new ArrayList<ExampleItem>();
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    private ExampleAdapterListener listener;

    public ExampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ExampleItem> bookslist, ExampleAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.mExampleList = bookslist;
        this.contactListFiltered = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    contactListFiltered = mExampleList;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<ExampleItem> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (ExampleItem row : mExampleList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    contactListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = contactListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                contactListFiltered = (ArrayList<ExampleItem>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);

        void onClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }




    // Here I added the update list function
    public void updateList(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList) {
        mExampleList = exampleList;
        contactListFiltered = exampleList; // Add the exampleList here as well
    }

    @Override
    public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
        return new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);


         String title = currentItem.getTitle();
//        int likeCount = currentItem.getLikeCount();
//        String imageUrl = currentItem.getImageUrl();

          holder.mTextViewCreator.setText(title);
//        holder.mTextViewLikes.setText("Likes: " + likeCount);
//        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageUrl).apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform()).into(holder.mImageView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return contactListFiltered.size();
    }

    public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        public TextView mTextViewCreator;
//        public TextView mTextViewLikes;
//        public ImageView mImageView;

        public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            mTextViewLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view_likes);
//            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
            mTextViewCreator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mListener != null) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    mListener.onItemClick(position);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    public interface ExampleAdapterListener {
        void onContactSelected(ExampleItem contact);
    }
}
```

and my fragment class is

```html
public class Mynotes extends Fragment implements ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, ExampleAdapter.ExampleAdapterListener {
    public static final String PDF_LINK = "link";
    private ProgressBar myProgressBar;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ExampleAdapter mExampleAdapter;
    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    String url="https://api.myjson.com/bins/16mecx";
    private SearchView searchView;

    public Mynotes() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_jsonfeed, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            url = bundle.getString("key_one");
        }


        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL, 36));

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorAccent, R.color.colorPrimary, R.color.colorBackground);

        myProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
        myProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        // SearchBox
        searchView = (SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryString) {
                mExampleAdapter.getFilter().filter(queryString);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String queryString) {
                mExampleAdapter.getFilter().filter(queryString);
                return false;
            }
        });

        updateListContent();
        mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        mExampleAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(getActivity(), mExampleList,this);
        mExampleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);


        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mExampleAdapter);

        mExampleAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);

 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    updateListContent();
                }
            });



        return view;
    }

    public void updateListContent() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        if (mExampleList != null)
            mExampleList.clear();
        parseJSON();
    }

    private void parseJSON() {
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("hits");

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject hit = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String videoTitle = hit.getString("title");
                                String link = hit.getString("link");
                                String doc = hit.getString("doc");

                                mExampleList.add(new ExampleItem(videoTitle, link,doc));
                                // Move this outside of the for loop
                                // mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

                            // Update the list here and then call notifyDataSetChanged
                            mExampleAdapter.updateList(mExampleList);
                            mExampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        mRequestQueue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Intent ytdIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), Pdfviewer.class);
        ExampleItem clickedItem = mExampleList.get(position);
        ytdIntent.putExtra(PDF_LINK, clickedItem.getmDocs());
        startActivity(ytdIntent);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onContactSelected(ExampleItem contact) {

    }
}
```

and my json url is 
[enter link description here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/16mecx).  If any more information is required. I'll add. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution bro.??

Comment: @MustafaShaikh not yet

Comment: same problem so i created API to search.

Comment: @MustafaShaikh  can you share it with me and how to use it?

Comment: Say to back-end team to create GET API and use it with search  onQueryTextSubmit and onQueryTextChange  and pass your variable to API

Comment: I have found a solution for this bro let me answer and try it 100% working

Answer (score 0):

Make two list for filter

```
       List<ProdectModel> prodectModels ;
         List<ProdectModel> productFilterList;

     public BookAdapter(Context context, List<ProdectModel> bookModels, String title,String Cat_id) {
            this.context = context;
            this.prodectModels = bookModels;
            this.title = title;
            this.Cat_id = Cat_id;
            this.productFilterList = new ArrayList<>();
            this.productFilterList.addAll(this.prodectModels);
        }

 private static String removeAccent(String text) {
        String result = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
        return result.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
    }

  public void searchCompanyes(CharSequence charText) {

        charText = removeAccent((String) charText).toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

        prodectModels.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            prodectModels.addAll(productFilterList);
        } else {
            for (ProdectModel Company : productFilterList) {
                String name = removeAccent(Company.getName());
                if (name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    prodectModels.add(Company);
                }
            }
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And finally call the method in activity and pass your text in that